# ¿Como puedo hacer este efecto de subrayado con CSS?

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo un reto de frontend mentor y veo que en el diseño tengo que realizar este subrayado en un boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo primero que pense es que era un border-bottom con border-radius, pero claramente no funciono.

Estoy a punto de utilizar un div y realizar una linea y hacer ese efecto, seria lo mas sencillo pero no creo que sea la forma correcta de hacerlo, alguno tiene alguna idea?

Este es mi boton:

```css
button{
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    background:none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: rgba(255, 238, 0, 0.829) 5px solid;
    border-end-end-radius: 7px
    }
```

```html
 <button>Learn more</button>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me podrías proporcionar el link de ese botón que viste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con la propiedad `content` de **CSS** y el **pseudoelemento** `::after`

Con `::after` podemos insertar un pseudo-elemento al final de un elemento y este es susceptible de ser modificado con **CSS**. A través de `content` insertamos un contenido vacío (a efectos sería como insertar un `<div>` vacío) y le damos el aspecto que deseamos.

Si te fijas, es la idea que descartaste de hacerlo con un `<div>` (que tampoco lo veo como una mala solución) pero maquillada un poco.

```css
.subrayado {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  background:none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.subrayado::after {
  content: '';
  height: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(251 242 175);
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="subrayado">Learn more</button>
```

**Referencias:** [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!